# How to set log level in Selenium 2 WebDriver TestNg tests run through Ant

Tags: java, ant, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm implementing a set of Selenium WebDriver tests in Java and I created the following ant build file that runs all the tests:

```
<project name="selenium" default="test" basedir=".">

 <path id="cp">
   <pathelement location="lib/testng-6.3.1.jar"/>
   <pathelement location="lib/jcommander-1.13.jar"/>
   <pathelement location="lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar"/>
   <pathelement location="lib/selenium-java-2.15.0.jar"/>
   <pathelement location="lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar"/>
   <pathelement location="bin"/>
 </path>

 <taskdef name="testng" classpathref="cp"
          classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />

 <target name="test" depends="compile">
   <testng classpathref="cp" haltOnFailure="false">
     <classfileset dir="bin" includes="org/rnig/selenium/**/*Test.class"/>     
   </testng>
 </target>

 <target name="clean">
   <delete dir="bin" />
 </target>

 <target name="compile" depends="clean">
   <mkdir dir="bin" />
   <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" classpathref="cp" includeantruntime="no" />
 </target>

</project>
```

When I execute "ant test" in the command line everything works fine BUT I get a huge amount of logging messages in the screen:

```
(...)
   [testng] Dec 14, 2011 4:17:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver execute
   [testng] INFO: Executing: [1323679961495, executeScript {"script":"return (function() { return (function(){return function(){function f(a){throw a;}var i=void 0,j=null,l,n=this;\nfunction aa(a){var b=typeof a;if(b==\"object\")if(a){if(a instanceof Array)return\"array\";else if(a instanceof Object)return b;var c=Object.prototype.toString.call(a);if(c==\"[object Window]\")return\"object\";if(c==\"[object Array]\"||typeof a.length==\"number\"&&typeof a.splice!=\"undefined\"&&typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable!=\"undefined\"&&!a.propertyIsEnumerable(\"splice\"))return\"array\";if(c==\"[object Function]\"||typeof a.call!=\"undefined\"&&typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable!=\"undefined\"&&!a.propertyIsEnumerable(\"call\"))return\"function\"}else return\"null\";\nelse if(b==\"function\"&&typeof a.call==\"undefined\")return\"object\";return b}function o(a){return typeof a==\"string\"}function p(a){return aa(a)==\"function\"}function ba(a){a=aa(a);return a==\"object\"||a==\"array\"||a==\"function\"}var ca=\"closure_uid_\"+Math.floor(Math.random()*2147483648).toString(36),da=0;function ea(a){var b=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);return function(){var c=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);c.unshift.apply(c,b);return a.apply(this,c)}}var fa=Date.now||function(){return+new Date};\nfunction q(a,b){function c(){}c.prototype=b.prototype;a.H=b.prototype;a.prototype=new c};function ga(a,b){var c=a.length-b.length;return c>=0&&a.indexOf(b,c)==c}function ha(a){for(var b=1;b<arguments.length;b++)var c=String(arguments[b]).replace(/\\$/g,\"$$$$\"),a=a.replace(/\\%s/,c);return a}function s(a){return a.replace(/^[\\s\\xa0]+|[\\s\\xa0]+$/g,\"\")}function ia(a,b){if(a<b)return-1;else if(a>b)return 1;return 0}var ja={};function ka(a){return ja[a]||(ja[a]=String(a).replace(/\\-([a-z])/g,function(a,c){return c.toUpperCase()}))};var la={},t,ma,u,na;function oa(){return n.navigator?n.navigator.userAgent:j}na=u=ma=t=!1;var v;if(v=oa()){var pa=n.navigator;t=v.indexOf(\"Opera\")==0;ma=!t&&v.indexOf(\"MSIE\")!=-1;u=!t&&v.indexOf(\"WebKit\")!=-1;na=!t&&!u&&pa.product==\"Gecko\"}var qa=t,w=ma,x=na,y=u,ra=n.navigator,sa=(ra&&ra.platform||\"\").indexOf(\"Mac\")!=-1,z;\na:{var ta=\"\",A;if(qa&&n.opera)var ua=n.opera.version,ta=typeof ua==\"function\"?ua():ua;else if(x?A=/rv\\:([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/:w?A=/MSIE\\s+([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/:y&&(A=/WebKit\\/(\\S+)/),A)var va=A.exec(oa()),ta=va?va[1]:\"\";if(w){var wa,xa=n.document;wa=xa?xa.documentMode:i;if(wa>parseFloat(ta)){z=String(wa);break a}}z=ta}var ya={};\nfunction B(a){var b;if(!(b=ya[a])){b=0;for(var c=s(String(z)).split(\".\"),d=s(String(a)).split(\".\"),e=Math.max(c.length,d.length),h=0;b==0&&h<e;h++){var g=c[h]||\"\",k=d[h]||\"\",m=RegExp(\"(\\\\d*)(\\\\D*)\",\"g\"),r=RegExp(\"(\\\\d*)(\\\\D*)\",\"g\");do{var P=m.exec(g)||[\"\",\"\",\"\"],Q=r.exec(k)||[\"\",\"\",\"\"];if(P[0].length==0&&Q[0].length==0)break;b=ia(P[1].length==0?0:parseInt(P[1],10),Q[1].length==0?0:parseInt(Q[1],10))||ia(P[2].length==0,Q[2].length==0)||ia(P[2],Q[2])}while(b==0)}b=ya[a]=b>=0}return b}var za={};\nfunction Aa(){return za[9]||(za[9]=w&&document.documentMode&&document.documentMode>=9)};var C=window;function D(a){this.stack=Error().stack||\"\";if(a)this.message=String(a)}q(D,Error);D.prototype.name=\"CustomError\";function E(a,b){D.call(this,b);this.code=a;this.name=Ba[a]||Ba[13]}q(E,D);\nvar Ba,Ca={NoSuchElementError:7,NoSuchFrameError:8,UnknownCommandError:9,StaleElementReferenceError:10,ElementNotVisibleError:11,InvalidElementStateError:12,UnknownError:13,ElementNotSelectableError:15,XPathLookupError:19,NoSuchWindowError:23,InvalidCookieDomainError:24,UnableToSetCookieError:25,ModalDialogOpenedError:26,NoModalDialogOpenError:27,ScriptTimeoutError:28,InvalidSelectorError:32,SqlDatabaseError:33,MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError:34},Da={},Ea;for(Ea in Ca)Da[Ca[Ea]]=Ea;Ba=Da;\nE.prototype.toString=function(){return\"[\"+this.name+\"] \"+this.message};function Fa(a,b){b.unshift(a);D.call(this,ha.apply(j,b));b.shift();this.J=a}q(Fa,D);Fa.prototype.name=\"AssertionError\";function F(a,b){if(o(a)){if(!o(b)||b.length!=1)return-1;return a.indexOf(b,0)}for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++)if(c in a&&a[c]===b)return c;return-1}function Ga(a,b){for(var c=a.length,d=o(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,e=0;e<c;e++)e in d&&b.call(i,d[e],e,a)}function G(a,b){for(var c=a.length,d=[],e=0,h=o(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,g=0;g<c;g++)if(g in h){var k=h[g];b.call(i,k,g,a)&&(d[e++]=k)}return d}function Ha(a,b){for(var c=a.length,d=o(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,e=0;e<c;e++)if(e in d&&b.call(i,d[e],e,a))return!0;return!1}\nfunction Ia(a,b){var c;a:{c=a.length;for(var d=o(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,e=0;e<c;e++)if(e in d&&b.call(i,d[e],e,a)){c=e;break a}c=-1}return c<0?j:o(a)?a.charAt(c):a[c]};var Ja;!w||Aa();!x&&!w||w&&Aa()||x&&B(\"1.9.1\");w&&B(\"9\");function Ka(a,b){this.width=a;this.height=b}Ka.prototype.toString=function(){return\"(\"+this.width+\" x \"+this.height+\")\"};Ka.prototype.floor=function(){this.width=Math.floor(this.width);this.height=Math.floor(this.height);return this};var La=3;function H(a){return a?new Ma(I(a)):Ja||(Ja=new Ma)}\nfunction Na(a,b,c,d){a=d||a;b=b&&b!=\"*\"?b.toUpperCase():\"\";if(a.querySelectorAll&&a.querySelector&&(!y||document.compatMode==\"CSS1Compat\"||B(\"528\"))&&(b||c))return a.querySelectorAll(b+(c?\".\"+c:\"\"));if(c&&a.getElementsByClassName)if(a=a.getElementsByClassName(c),b){for(var d={},e=0,h=0,g;g=a[h];h++)b==g.nodeName&&(d[e++]=g);d.length=e;return d}else return a;a=a.getElementsByTagName(b||\"*\");if(c){d={};for(h=e=0;g=a[h];h++)b=g.className,typeof b.split==\"function\"&&F(b.split(/\\s+/),c)>=0&&(d[e++]=g);\nd.length=e;return d}else return a}function Oa(a,b){if(a.contains&&b.nodeType==1)return a==b||a.contains(b);if(typeof a.compareDocumentPosition!=\"undefined\")return a==b||Boolean(a.compareDocumentPosition(b)&16);for(;b&&a!=b;)b=b.parentNode;return b==a}function I(a){return a.nodeType==9?a:a.ownerDocument||a.document}function Pa(a,b){var c=[];return Qa(a,b,c,!0)?c[0]:i}\nfunction Qa(a,b,c,d){if(a!=j)for(a=a.firstChild;a;){if(b(a)&&(c.push(a),d))return!0;if(Qa(a,b,c,d))return!0;a=a.nextSibling}return!1}function Ra(a,b){for(var a=a.parentNode,c=0;a;){if(b(a))return a;a=a.parentNode;c++}return j}function Ma(a){this.i=a||n.document||document}function J(a,b,c,d){return Na(a.i,b,c,d)}Ma.prototype.contains=Oa;var K={};K.s=function(){var a={L:\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"};return function(b){return a[b]||j}}();K.k=function(a,b,c){var d=I(a);if(!d.implementation.hasFeature(\"XPath\",\"3.0\"))return j;var e=d.createNSResolver?d.createNSResolver(d.documentElement):K.s;return d.evaluate(b,a,e,c,j)};K.m=function(a){return\"NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE\"!=a.name};\nK.b=function(a,b){var c=function(b,c){var h=I(b);try{if(b.selectSingleNode)return h.setProperty&&h.setProperty(\"SelectionLanguage\",\"XPath\"),b.selectSingleNode(c);var g=K.k(b,c,9);return g?g.singleNodeValue:j}catch(k){return K.m(k)&&f(new E(32,\"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression \"+a+\" because of the following error:\\n\"+k)),j}}(b,a);if(!c)return j;c.nodeType!=1&&f(new E(32,'The result of the xpath expression \"'+a+'\" is: '+c+\". It should be an element.\"));return c};\nK.e=function(a,b){var c=function(a,b){var c=I(a),g;try{if(a.selectNodes)return c.setProperty&&c.setProperty(\"SelectionLanguage\",\"XPath\"),a.selectNodes(b);g=K.k(a,b,7)}catch(k){K.m(k)&&f(new E(32,\"Unable to locate elements with the xpath expression \"+b+\" because of the following error:\\n\"+k))}c=[];if(g)for(var m=g.snapshotLength,r=0;r<m;++r)c.push(g.snapshotItem(r));return c}(b,a);Ga(c,function(b){b.nodeType!=1&&f(new E(32,'The result of the xpath expression \"'+a+'\" is: '+b+\". It should be an element.\"))});\nreturn c};var Sa=\"StopIteration\"in n?n.StopIteration:Error(\"StopIteration\");function Ta(){}Ta.prototype.next=function(){f(Sa)};function L(a,b,c,d,e){this.a=!!b;a&&M(this,a,d);this.f=e!=i?e:this.d||0;this.a&&(this.f*=-1);this.v=!c}q(L,Ta);l=L.prototype;l.c=j;l.d=0;l.q=!1;function M(a,b,c){if(a.c=b)a.d=typeof c==\"number\"?c:a.c.nodeType!=1?0:a.a?-1:1}\nl.next=function(){var a;if(this.q){(!this.c||this.v&&this.f==0)&&f(Sa);a=this.c;var b=this.a?-1:1;if(this.d==b){var c=this.a?a.lastChild:a.firstChild;c?M(this,c):M(this,a,b*-1)}else(c=this.a?a.previousSibling:a.nextSibling)?M(this,c):M(this,a.parentNode,b*-1);this.f+=this.d*(this.a?-1:1)}else this.q=!0;(a=this.c)||f(Sa);return a};\nl.splice=function(){var a=this.c,b=this.a?1:-1;if(this.d==b)this.d=b*-1,this.f+=this.d*(this.a?-1:1);this.a=!this.a;L.prototype.next.call(this);this.a=!this.a;for(var b=arguments[0],c=aa(b),b=c==\"array\"||c==\"object\"&&typeof b.length==\"number\"?arguments[0]:arguments,c=b.length-1;c>=0;c--)a.parentNode&&a.parentNode.insertBefore(b[c],a.nextSibling);a&&a.parentNode&&a.parentNode.removeChild(a)};function Ua(a,b,c,d){L.call(this,a,b,c,j,d)}q(Ua,L);Ua.prototype.next=function(){do Ua.H.next.call(this);while(this.d==-1);return this.c};function Va(a,b){var c=I(a);if(c.defaultView&&c.defaultView.getComputedStyle&&(c=c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a,j)))return c[b]||c.getPropertyValue(b);return\"\"}function Wa(a){var b=a.offsetWidth,c=a.offsetHeight,d=y&&!b&&!c;if((b===i||d)&&a.getBoundingClientRect){b=a.getBoundingClientRect();if(w)a=a.ownerDocument,b.left-=a.documentElement.clientLeft+a.body.clientLeft,b.top-=a.documentElement.clientTop+a.body.clientTop;return new Ka(b.right-b.left,b.bottom-b.top)}return new Ka(b,c)};function N(a,b){return!!a&&a.nodeType==1&&(!b||a.tagName.toUpperCase()==b)}var Xa={\"class\":\"className\",readonly:\"readOnly\"},Ya=[\"checked\",\"disabled\",\"draggable\",\"hidden\"];function Za(a,b){var c=Xa[b]||b,d=a[c];if(d===i&&F(Ya,c)>=0)return!1;return d}\nvar $a=[\"async\",\"autofocus\",\"autoplay\",\"checked\",\"compact\",\"complete\",\"controls\",\"declare\",\"defaultchecked\",\"defaultselected\",\"defer\",\"disabled\",\"draggable\",\"ended\",\"formnovalidate\",\"hidden\",\"indeterminate\",\"iscontenteditable\",\"ismap\",\"itemscope\",\"loop\",\"multiple\",\"muted\",\"nohref\",\"noresize\",\"noshade\",\"novalidate\",\"nowrap\",\"open\",\"paused\",\"pubdate\",\"readonly\",\"required\",\"reversed\",\"scoped\",\"seamless\",\"seeking\",\"selected\",\"spellcheck\",\"truespeed\",\"willvalidate\"];\nfunction O(a,b){if(8==a.nodeType)return j;b=b.toLowerCase();if(b==\"style\"){var c=s(a.style.cssText).toLowerCase();return c.charAt(c.length-1)==\";\"?c:c+\";\"}c=a.getAttributeNode(b);w&&!c&&B(8)&&F($a,b)>=0&&(c=a[b]);if(!c)return j;if(F($a,b)>=0)return w&&c.value==\"false\"?j:\"true\";return c.specified?c.value:j}function ab(a){for(a=a.parentNode;a&&a.nodeType!=1&&a.nodeType!=9&&a.nodeType!=11;)a=a.parentNode;return N(a)?a:j}function R(a,b){b=ka(b);return Va(a,b)||bb(a,b)}\nfunction bb(a,b){var c=a.currentStyle||a.style,d=c[b];d===i&&p(c.getPropertyValue)&&(d=c.getPropertyValue(b));if(d!=\"inherit\")return d!==i?d:j;return(c=ab(a))?bb(c,b):j}\nfunction cb(a){if(p(a.getBBox))return a.getBBox();var b;if((Va(a,\"display\")||(a.currentStyle?a.currentStyle.display:j)||a.style&&a.style.display)!=\"none\")b=Wa(a);else{b=a.style;var c=b.display,d=b.visibility,e=b.position;b.visibility=\"hidden\";b.position=\"absolute\";b.display=\"inline\";a=Wa(a);b.display=c;b.position=e;b.visibility=d;b=a}return b}\nfunction db(a,b){function c(a){if(R(a,\"display\")==\"none\")return!1;a=ab(a);return!a||c(a)}function d(a){var b=cb(a);if(b.height>0&&b.width>0)return!0;return Ha(a.childNodes,function(a){return a.nodeType==La||N(a)&&d(a)})}N(a)||f(Error(\"Argument to isShown must be of type Element\"));if(N(a,\"OPTION\")||N(a,\"OPTGROUP\")){var e=Ra(a,function(a){return N(a,\"SELECT\")});return!!e&&db(e,!0)}if(N(a,\"MAP\")){if(!a.name)return!1;e=I(a);e=e.evaluate?K.b('/descendant::*[@usemap = \"#'+a.name+'\"]',e):Pa(e,function(b){return N(b)&&\nO(b,\"usemap\")==\"#\"+a.name});return!!e&&db(e,b)}if(N(a,\"AREA\"))return e=Ra(a,function(a){return N(a,\"MAP\")}),!!e&&db(e,b);if(N(a,\"INPUT\")&&a.type.toLowerCase()==\"hidden\")return!1;if(R(a,\"visibility\")==\"hidden\")return!1;if(!c(a))return!1;if(!b&&eb(a)==0)return!1;if(!d(a))return!1;return!0}function fb(a){return a.replace(/^[^\\S\\xa0]+|[^\\S\\xa0]+$/g,\"\")}\nfunction gb(a){var b=[];hb(a,b);for(var c=b,a=c.length,b=Array(a),c=o(c)?c.split(\"\"):c,d=0;d<a;d++)d in c&&(b[d]=fb.call(i,c[d]));return fb(b.join(\"\\n\")).replace(/\\xa0/g,\" \")}\nfunction hb(a,b){if(N(a,\"BR\"))b.push(\"\");else{var c=N(a,\"TD\"),d=R(a,\"display\"),e=!c&&!(F(ib,d)>=0);e&&!/^[\\s\\xa0]*$/.test(b[b.length-1]||\"\")&&b.push(\"\");var h=db(a),g=j,k=j;h&&(g=R(a,\"white-space\"),k=R(a,\"text-transform\"));Ga(a.childNodes,function(a){a.nodeType==La&&h?jb(a,b,g,k):N(a)&&hb(a,b)});var m=b[b.length-1]||\"\";if((c||d==\"table-cell\")&&m&&!ga(m,\" \"))b[b.length-1]+=\" \";e&&!/^[\\s\\xa0]*$/.test(m)&&b.push(\"\")}}var ib=[\"inline\",\"inline-block\",\"inline-table\",\"none\",\"table-cell\",\"table-column\",\"table-column-group\"];\nfunction jb(a,b,c,d){a=a.nodeValue.replace(/\\u200b/g,\"\");a=a.replace(/(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)/g,\"\\n\");if(c==\"normal\"||c==\"nowrap\")a=a.replace(/\\n/g,\" \");a=c==\"pre\"||c==\"pre-wrap\"?a.replace(/[ \\f\\t\\v\\u2028\\u2029]/g,\"\\u00a0\"):a.replace(/[\\ \\f\\t\\v\\u2028\\u2029]+/g,\" \");d==\"capitalize\"?a=a.replace(/(^|\\s)(\\S)/g,function(a,b,c){return b+c.toUpperCase()}):d==\"uppercase\"?a=a.toUpperCase():d==\"lowercase\"&&(a=a.toLowerCase());c=b.pop()||\"\";ga(c,\" \")&&a.lastIndexOf(\" \",0)==0&&(a=a.substr(1));b.push(c+a)}\nfunction eb(a){if(w){if(R(a,\"position\")==\"relative\")return 1;a=R(a,\"filter\");return(a=a.match(/^alpha\\(opacity=(\\d*)\\)/)||a.match(/^progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha\\(Opacity=(\\d*)\\)/))?Number(a[1])/100:1}else return kb(a)}function kb(a){var b=1,c=R(a,\"opacity\");c&&(b=Number(c));(a=ab(a))&&(b*=kb(a));return b};function S(a){D.call(this,a)}q(S,D);!w||Aa();!w||Aa();w&&B(\"8\");!y||B(\"528\");x&&B(\"1.9b\")||w&&B(\"8\")||qa&&B(\"9.5\")||y&&B(\"528\");!x||B(\"8\");function lb(){mb&&(this[ca]||(this[ca]=++da))}var mb=!1;function T(a,b){lb.call(this);this.type=a;this.currentTarget=this.target=b}q(T,lb);T.prototype.D=!1;T.prototype.F=!0;function nb(a){nb[\" \"](a);return a}nb[\" \"]=function(){};function ob(a,b){if(a){var c=this.type=a.type;T.call(this,c);this.target=a.target||a.srcElement;this.currentTarget=b;var d=a.relatedTarget;if(d){if(x){var e;a:{try{nb(d.nodeName);e=!0;break a}catch(h){}e=!1}e||(d=j)}}else if(c==\"mouseover\")d=a.fromElement;else if(c==\"mouseout\")d=a.toElement;this.relatedTarget=d;this.offsetX=a.offsetX!==i?a.offsetX:a.layerX;this.offsetY=a.offsetY!==i?a.offsetY:a.layerY;this.clientX=a.clientX!==i?a.clientX:a.pageX;this.clientY=a.clientY!==i?a.clientY:a.pageY;this.screenX=\na.screenX||0;this.screenY=a.screenY||0;this.button=a.button;this.keyCode=a.keyCode||0;this.charCode=a.charCode||(c==\"keypress\"?a.keyCode:0);this.ctrlKey=a.ctrlKey;this.altKey=a.altKey;this.shiftKey=a.shiftKey;this.metaKey=a.metaKey;this.C=sa?a.metaKey:a.ctrlKey;this.state=a.state;this.w=a;delete this.F;delete this.D}}q(ob,T);l=ob.prototype;l.target=j;l.relatedTarget=j;l.offsetX=0;l.offsetY=0;l.clientX=0;l.clientY=0;l.screenX=0;l.screenY=0;l.button=0;l.keyCode=0;l.charCode=0;l.ctrlKey=!1;\nl.altKey=!1;l.shiftKey=!1;l.metaKey=!1;l.C=!1;l.w=j;var U={g:function(a){return!(!a.querySelectorAll||!a.querySelector)}};U.b=function(a,b){a||f(Error(\"No class name specified\"));a=s(a);a.split(/\\s+/).length>1&&f(Error(\"Compound class names not permitted\"));if(U.g(b))return b.querySelector(\".\"+a.replace(/\\./g,\"\\\\.\"))||j;var c=J(H(b),\"*\",a,b);return c.length?c[0]:j};\nU.e=function(a,b){a||f(Error(\"No class name specified\"));a=s(a);a.split(/\\s+/).length>1&&f(Error(\"Compound class names not permitted\"));if(U.g(b))return b.querySelectorAll(\".\"+a.replace(/\\./g,\"\\\\.\"));return J(H(b),\"*\",a,b)};var V={};V.b=function(a,b){!p(b.querySelector)&&w&&B(8)&&!ba(b.querySelector)&&f(Error(\"CSS selection is not supported\"));a||f(Error(\"No selector specified\"));V.h(a)&&f(Error(\"Compound selectors not permitted\"));var a=s(a),c=b.querySelector(a);return c&&c.nodeType==1?c:j};V.e=function(a,b){!p(b.querySelectorAll)&&w&&B(8)&&!ba(b.querySelector)&&f(Error(\"CSS selection is not supported\"));a||f(Error(\"No selector specified\"));V.h(a)&&f(Error(\"Compound selectors not permitted\"));a=s(a);return b.querySelectorAll(a)};\nV.h=function(a){return a.split(/(,)(?=(?:[^']|'[^']*')*$)/).length>1&&a.split(/(,)(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)/).length>1};var W={},pb={};W.p=function(a,b,c){b=J(H(b),\"A\",j,b);return Ia(b,function(b){b=gb(b);return c&&b.indexOf(a)!=-1||b==a})};W.n=function(a,b,c){b=J(H(b),\"A\",j,b);return G(b,function(b){b=gb(b);return c&&b.indexOf(a)!=-1||b==a})};W.b=function(a,b){return W.p(a,b,!1)};W.e=function(a,b){return W.n(a,b,!1)};pb.b=function(a,b){return W.p(a,b,!0)};pb.e=function(a,b){return W.n(a,b,!0)};var qb={b:function(a,b){return b.getElementsByTagName(a)[0]||j},e:function(a,b){return b.getElementsByTagName(a)}};var rb={className:U,\"class name\":U,css:V,\"css selector\":V,id:{b:function(a,b){var c=H(b),d=o(a)?c.i.getElementById(a):a;if(!d)return j;if(O(d,\"id\")==a&&Oa(b,d))return d;c=J(c,\"*\");return Ia(c,function(c){return O(c,\"id\")==a&&Oa(b,c)})},e:function(a,b){var c=J(H(b),\"*\",j,b);return G(c,function(b){return O(b,\"id\")==a})}},linkText:W,\"link text\":W,name:{b:function(a,b){var c=J(H(b),\"*\",j,b);return Ia(c,function(b){return O(b,\"name\")==a})},e:function(a,b){var c=J(H(b),\"*\",j,b);return G(c,function(b){return O(b,\n\"name\")==a})}},partialLinkText:pb,\"partial link text\":pb,tagName:qb,\"tag name\":qb,xpath:K};function sb(a,b){var c;a:{for(c in a)if(a.hasOwnProperty(c))break a;c=j}if(c){var d=rb[c];if(d&&p(d.b))return d.b(a[c],b||C.document)}f(Error(\"Unsupported locator strategy: \"+c))};var tb={index:function(a,b){a=Number(a);(isNaN(a)||a<0)&&f(new S(\"Illegal Index: \"+a));b.length<=a&&f(new S(\"Index out of range: \"+a));return[b[a]]},name:function(a,b){return G(b,function(b){return Za(b,\"name\")==a})},value:function(a,b){return G(b,function(b){return Za(b,\"value\")===a})}};var X={};X.A=function(a,b){if(a.lastIndexOf(\"//\",0)==0)return X.r(a,b);if(a.lastIndexOf(\"document.\",0)==0)return X.j(a);return X.l(a,b)};X.t=function(a,b){return ub(b||I(C),function(b){return b.alt==a})};X.u=function(a,b){return ub(b||I(C),function(b){return b.className==a})};X.j=function(a){var b=j;try{b=eval(a)}catch(c){return j}return b?b:j};X.z=function(a,b){return sb({id:a},b)};X.l=function(a,b){return X.id(a,b)||X.name(a,b)};\nX.B=function(a,b){var c=b||I(C);H(c);var d=Na(document,\"*\",j,c),c=a.split(\" \");for(c[0]=\"name=\"+c[0];c.length;){var e=c.shift(),h=\"value\",g=e.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)=(.+)/);g&&(h=g[1].toLowerCase(),e=g[2]);(g=tb[h])||f(new S(\"Unrecognised element-filter type: '\"+h+\"'\"));d=g(e,d)}return d.length>0?d[0]:j};\nX.G=function(a,b){try{var c;a:{var d;d=decodeURIComponent(a);var e=b||document,h,g=e||document,k=g.$wdc_;if(!k)k=g.$wdc_={},k.o=fa();if(!k.o)k.o=fa();h=k;d in h||f(new E(10,\"Element does not exist in cache\"));var m=h[d];if(\"document\"in m)m.closed&&(delete h[d],f(new E(23,\"Window has been closed.\"))),c=m;else{for(g=m;g;){if(g==e.documentElement){c=m;break a}g=g.parentNode}delete h[d];f(new E(10,\"Element is no longer attached to the DOM\"))}}return c}catch(r){return j}};\nX.r=function(a,b){var c=ga(a,\"/\"),d={xpath:a};try{var e=sb(d,b);if(e||!c)return e}catch(h){c||f(h)}d={xpath:a.substring(0,a.length-1)};return sb(d,b)};X.alt=X.t;X[\"class\"]=X.u;X.dom=X.j;X.id=X.z;X.identifier=X.l;X.implicit=X.A;X.name=X.B;X.stored=X.G;X.xpath=X.r;function vb(a,b,c,d){var e=X[a];e||f(new S(\"Unrecognised locator type: '\"+a+\"'\"));c=e.call(j,b,c);if(c!=j)return c;if(!d)return j;for(e=0;e<d.frames.length;e++){var h;try{h=d.frames[e].document}catch(g){}if(h&&(c=vb(a,b,h,d.frames[e]),c!=j))return c}return j}function ub(a,b){for(var c=a.childNodes.length,d=0;d<c;d++){var e=a.childNodes[d];if(e.nodeType==1){if(b(e))return e;if(e=ub(e,b))return e}}return j};function wb(a,b){return RegExp(a).test(b)}function xb(a,b){return RegExp(a,\"i\").text(b)}function yb(a){a=a.replace(/([.^$+(){}\\[\\]\\\\|])/g,\"\\\\$1\");a=a.replace(/\\?/g,\"(.|[\\r\\n])\");return a=a.replace(/\\*/g,\"(.|[\\r\\n])*\")}var zb={exact:function(a,b){return b.indexOf(a)!=-1},glob:function(a,b){return RegExp(\"^\"+yb(a)+\"$\").test(b)},globcontains:function(a,b){return RegExp(yb(a)).test(b)},regex:wb,regexi:xb,regexpi:xb,regexp:wb};function Ab(a,b){if(a.style&&(a.style.visibility==\"hidden\"||a.style.display==\"none\"))return\"\";var c;if(a.nodeType==La)return c=a.data,b||(c=c.replace(/\\n|\\r|\\t/g,\" \")),c.replace(/&nbsp/,\" \");if(a.nodeType==1&&a.nodeName!=\"SCRIPT\"){var d=b||a.tagName==\"PRE\";c=\"\";for(var e=0;e<a.childNodes.length;e++){var h=a.childNodes.item(e);c+=Ab(h,d)}if(a.tagName==\"P\"||a.tagName==\"BR\"||a.tagName==\"HR\"||a.tagName==\"DIV\")c+=\"\\n\";return c.replace(/&nbsp/,\" \")}return\"\"}\nfunction Bb(a){if(o(a)){var b;b=a;var c=b.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)=.+/);c?(c=c[1].toLowerCase(),b={type:c,string:b.substring(c.length+1)}):(c={string:\"\",type:\"\"},c.string=b,c.type=b.lastIndexOf(\"//\",0)==0?\"xpath\":b.lastIndexOf(\"document.\",0)==0?\"dom\":\"identifier\",b=c);c=C||C;b=vb(b.type,b.string,c.document,c);b=b!=j?b:j;b==j&&f(new S(\"Element \"+a+\" not found\"));a=b}b=\"\";if(x&&z>=\"1.8\"||la.I||y||qa)b=Ab(a);else if(a.textContent)b=a.textContent;else if(a.innerText)b=a.innerText;b=b.replace(/\\r\\n|\\r/g,\"\\n\");\na=b;if(!w)if(a=a.replace(/\\ +/g,\" \"),b=RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160),\"g\"),y)for(b=String.fromCharCode(160);a.indexOf(b)!=-1;)a=a.replace(b,\" \");else a=a.replace(b,\" \");b=a;return s(b)}\nX.link=function(a,b){for(var c=(b||I(C)).getElementsByTagName(\"a\"),d=0;d<c.length;d++){var e=c[d],h=Bb(e),g=a,k=\"glob\",m=/^([a-zA-Z-]+):(.*)/.exec(g);if(m){var r=m[1],m=m[2];zb[r.toLowerCase()]&&(k=r.toLowerCase(),g=m)}(r=zb[k])||f(new S(\"Cannot find pattern matching strategy: \"+k));k==\"glob\"?(g.indexOf(\"glob:\")==0&&(g=g.substring(5)),r=zb.glob):k==\"exact\"&&g.indexOf(\"exact:\")==0&&(g=g.substring(6));g=ea(r,g);g.K=k;if(g(h))return e}return j};var Y=\"_\".split(\".\"),Z=n;!(Y[0]in Z)&&Z.execScript&&Z.execScript(\"var \"+Y[0]);for(var $;Y.length&&($=Y.shift());)!Y.length&&Bb!==i?Z[$]=Bb:Z=Z[$]?Z[$]:Z[$]={};; return this._.apply(null,arguments);}.apply({navigator:typeof window!='undefined'?window.navigator:null}, arguments);}\n).apply(null, arguments);})(arguments[0]);","args":["//div[@class='errormessage'][1]"]}]
   [testng] Dec 14, 2011 4:17:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver execute
   [testng] INFO: Executing: [1323679961495, deleteAllCookies {}]
   [testng] Dec 14, 2011 4:17:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver execute
   [testng] INFO: Executing: [1323679961495, quit {}]
```

I assume the INFO messages come from the WebDriver library but I don't know how to change the log level. Any ideas?

BTW, I already tried:

```
LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
logs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.OFF);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

and:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

without luck, although with the latter INFO messages stop being printed in the Eclipse console.

**UPDATE**: Setting the standard java.util.logger logLevel to e.g. WARNING (as shown above) at the right place, in my case inside a @BeforeClass method, solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

What logging framework is used ? I would provide custom config file to it instead of setting it via API. I think java.util.logging is used, my choice would be jul--over-slf4j + slf4j-api + logback-classic, then set loggers and appenders in logback's config file.

Comment: I think java.util.logging is used too, although I'm not very familiar with Java logging mechanisms. I found out that setting the logging level at the right place does solve the issue. thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -2):

go through this following link : 
http://selenium-suresh.blogspot.in/2013/02/ant-generating-selenium-reports-using.html

Anand Palabhavi